# Using classes as structures trying to set pure functions as methods

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, architecture

Usually, classes in JavaScript are presented like this:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

As a fan of functional programming and as someone who want to make code scalable, I am tempted to have like this for the whole app instead:

```
calcArea({height, width}) {
    return height * width;
  }

class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  get area() {
    return calcArea(this);
  }
}
```

Basically transform classes into structures and make all methods with related functions abstracted. This way I can easily export the `calcArea` function
Does this make sense, I would like to hear some thoughts on this, are there good articles about these architectures approaches?
Thank you

Comment: If you want to use functional programming, you should probably avoid classes entirely, since they're stateful - use plain functions instead (like the one refactor of `calcArea` that you're doing, but there's still `Rectangle` causing problems)

Comment: Don't pass `this`, and instead pass `height` and `width` directly?

Comment: The problem is that I am using an ORM and I would not want a big refactoring @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FP facilitates code sharing because it clearly separates the *state* from its *transition logic*. I'd suggest to think about whether you really need to add all this supporting code, or you could just work with `state` and `transitions`?

Wouldn't the following be just as fine? And possibly clearer?

```js
const rect = { width: 100, height: 500 };

const toRectArea = (rect) => rect.width * rect.height;
const toTriagleArea = (triangle) => toRectArea(trianle) / 2;
```

Comment: You guys are right I will in this case get rid of the class